# Why prefer Ember.$() vs $()

Tags: jquery, ember.js, ember-cli

I see that on lot of Ember-cli projects jQuery is called with `Ember.$()` instead of `$()`.

Is there a specific reason?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Usually `Ember` has been imported already, and by using `Ember.$` you avoid referencing a global dependency.  It's not actually that great an idea, and you can actually import jQuery directly.

```
// you can name the import `$` is you do desire
import jQuery from 'jquery';

jQuery()
```

Do note, there is a difference between `Ember.$()` and `this.$()`.  The `this` version within components is the equivalent of `jQuery(this.element)`.

Comment: thanks I knew the difference between this.$() and Ember.$(), so it's just to not import jquery explicity, okay thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Generally, it's best to use this.$ within your controller, view, or component so that way the element selection stays within the scope of the component.

But if you must access jQuery not bound to a particular element, Ember.$ is the safer way, especially if you're dealing with some of the global jQuery queues, like pending ajax requests.  Using Ember.$ you're using the jQuery that's included with ember and not some other instance of JQuery.